# Cloud Functions Access From Another Project (Securing Endpoint)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two firebase projects (say A and B) and I want only authenticated users of each project can have permission to invoke functions in different project. For example, only signed-in users in project A can invoke functions in B on web app hosted on project A.

verifyToken method only works within the same project but not in two different projects due to audience property discrepancy.

in GCP console, there's permission tab on each functions where specific users or service accounts are managed but simply adding service account of project A to one of the project B functions did not work.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

client side (Project A)

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to backend via HTTPS
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

backend (Project B)

```
admin
  .auth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((token) => {
// proceed ..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Above code only works within the same project.

Comment: 1) What type of user authorization? 2) How are you creating the Identity Token? 3) Show your code for both items.

Comment: @JohnHanley edited.

Comment: The problem that you have is correct. Firebase authentication works within a Firebase project, not across projects. Verifying the Identity Token is project-specific. The `aud` and `iss` keys contain the Firebase Project ID. You might be able to manually write code to verify the Identity Token and accept different project IDs for your own use (not Firebase) such as using a service account to access Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. could you give me more details on "manually write code to verify the Identity Token and accept different project IDs for your own use (not Firebase) such as using a service account to access Cloud Functions"

Comment: An Identity Token is a based64 encoded Signed JWT. There are a number of JWT libraries that can assist you. Create a new question, once you have written code, on how to verify a Google OAuth Identity Token. This link will help you get started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

Comment: @JohnHanley awesome. thank you so much.